# Is the vector $(3,-1,0,-1)$ in the subspace of $\Bbb R^4$ spanned by the vectors $(2,-1,3,2)$, $(-1,1,1,-3)$, $(1,1,9,-5)$?

Tags: vector-spaces

Is the vector $(3,-1,0,-1)$ in the subspace of $\Bbb R^4$ spanned by the vectors $(2,-1,3,2)$, $(-1,1,1,-3)$, $(1,1,9,-5)$?

Comment: Sorry but don't you mena $\mathbb{R}^4 $ ?

Comment: As a quick comment as to why the title and the OP's "originally-stated" question contained $\mathbb{R}^{5}$ as the given $\mathbb{R}$-vector space - this problem is from Hoffman's & Kunze's, $Linear~Algebra$, 2nd Edition. See page 39, Exercise 3; the problem-statement contains $\mathbb{R}^{5}$ as a typo and Dominic's correction clears up this confusion.

Answer (score 5):

To find wether $(3,-1,0,-1)$ is in the span of the other vectors, solve the system:
$$(3,-1,0,-1)=\lambda_1(2,-1,3,2)+\lambda _2(-1,1,1,-3)+\lambda _3(1,1,9,-5)$$

If you get a solution, then the vector is the span. If you don't get a solution, then it isn't.

It's worth noting that the span of $(2,-1,3,2), (-1,1,1,-3), (1,1,9,-5)$ is exactly the set $\left\{\lambda_1(2,-1,3,2)+\lambda _2(-1,1,1,-3)+\lambda _3(1,1,9,-5):\lambda _1, \lambda _2, \lambda _3\in \Bbb R\right\}$

---

Alternatively you can consider the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}2& -1 &3 & 2\\ -1 &1 &1 &-3\\ 1 & 1 & 9 & -5 \\ 3 &-1 &0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$. Compute its determinant. If it's not $0$, then the four vectors are linearly independent. If it is $0$ they are linearly dependent. What does that tell you?

Answer (score 2):

You have this coefficient(augmented) matrix: $\begin{pmatrix}
2&-1&1&3\\
-1&1&1&-1\\
3&1&9&0\\
2&-3&-5&-1
\end{pmatrix}$

Reduce it to the row echelon form and check whether it is consistent.

You basically need to check whether after row reduction its last non-zero row has a pivot in the last column or not.If it has in the last column then the equation set is inconsistent so you dont have a solution.Else you have solution(infinitely many) implying that the vector belongs to the span of the given three vectors.

Answer (score -1):

if (3,-1,0,-1) be in span {(2,-1,3,2),(-1,1,1,-3),(1,1,9,-5)} then we must have
 (3,-1,0,-1)=$c_{1}$ (2,-1,3,2)+ $c_2$ (-1,1,1,-3)+ $c_3$ (1,1,9,-5)
so this system must have solution:

$2c_1 -c_2+c_3=3$

$-c_1 +c_2+c_3=-1$

$3c_1 +c_2+9c_3=0$

$2c_1 -3c_2-5c_3=-1$ 
since 3 first relation has unic answer and 3 end realations too and they cant have equal answer (then this system has not solution and (3-10-1)

Comment: The solution you stated above...is it not already given by Git Gud's first solution above...with some added detail?